# How to convert rows to columns in a Pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-science

I have a table containing price data for a set of products over 6 months. Each product has a unique id (sku_id) and can be from size 6-12. We measured the price each day, and generated a table similar to the example below. Source indicates what website the price was on (can be 1-4).

```
| sku_id | size | price | timestamp | source |

|    1   | 6.0  | 115.0 | 2021-01-10|   1    |
|    2   | 8.0  | 149.0 | 2021-01-10|   1    |
|    1   | 6.0  | 168.0 | 2021-01-10|   2    |
|    1   | 9.0  | 152.0 | 2021-01-10|   1    |
 ... 
|    1   | 9.0  | 152.0 | 2021-07-10|   1    |
```

Now, I want to perform some analytics/modelling on the above dataset, but I'm having trouble formatting it as needed. I want one row for each product from each site (i.e. the key will be [sku_id, size, source]), where we get the price for each day from January 10th, to July 1st in a new column. This is represented in the table below.

```
| sku_id | size | source |price on 2021-01-10|price on 2021-01-11|price on 2021-01-12| ... |

|    1   | 6.0  |   1    |        149.0      |     151.2         |     158.2         | ... |
|    2   | 6.0  |   1    |        142.0      |     221.8         |     312.9         | ... |
 ...
```

I'm trying to do this in Pandas using a group by (grouping by sku_id, size, and source), but I'm not sure how to instruct Pandas to tack a new column on for each day. Does anyone have instructions/advice on how to build this second table from the first one? I am not quite sure how to get the group by to work, and I don't know what other strategies could work either.

Comment: set index on date, unstack it. collapse your multi-index accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot` to transform your dataframe:

```
# pivot args: 1st -> index, 2nd -> columns, 3rd -> values
>>> df.pivot(['sku_id', 'size', 'source'], 'timestamp', 'price') \
      .rename_axis(columns=None).add_prefix('price on ').reset_index()

   sku_id  size  source  price on 2021-01-10  price on 2021-07-10
0       1   6.0       1                115.0                  NaN
1       1   6.0       2                168.0                  NaN
2       1   9.0       1                152.0                152.0
3       2   8.0       1                149.0                  NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting a KeyError: 'timestamp', is there some way to discard or catch impacted datapoints? I'm having trouble finding a fix online.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your expected output is correct. The value 149 is attached to `sku_id = 2` whereas this is marked under `sku_id = 1` in your expected output. It moves some values from observation to another.

Regardless:

```
>>> df.set_index(['sku_id', 'size', 'source', 'timestamp']).unstack()
                        price           
timestamp          2021-01-10 2021-07-10
sku_id size source                      
1      6.0  1           115.0        NaN
            2           168.0        NaN
       9.0  1           152.0      152.0
2      8.0  1           149.0        NaN
```

Then reduce your columnar multi-index: `df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]` to get `price 2021-01-10` etc. If you want a different form, format it to fit.

If you want repeated stuff, `reset_index`.